# Construct Hash in Jekyll/Liquid

Tags: hash, jekyll, liquid

I was wondering if is there any way to construct a hash variable in Jekyll/Liquid.

Maybe something like this:

```
{% assign x = { foo: 1, bar: 2 } %}
{{ x[foo] }}
{{ x[bar] }}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no filters to work on hashes except the `for` loop.
The only way to get a hash is from global or pages variables, data or collection.

A [generator plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) can do some computing before rendering.

You can also manipulate arrays. For now only with `push` and `unshift` as `pop` and `shift` are changing their behavior in Jekyll 3.

### Recipe

In `_config.yml` add a `emptyArray: []`

In your code just `{% assign myarray = site.emptyArray %}`.

You can now `push` and `unshift` anything in it like `{% assign myarray = myarray | push: "toto" %}` or any object/hash like page, post, data,...